# Configuring SSL in Apache2

Tags: ssl, apache2

I generated a new private key and a csr

```
root@univhub:/# openssl req -out /etc/ssl/certs/univhub.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout /etc/ssl/private/univhub.key
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
.............................................................+++
...............+++
writing new private key to '/etc/ssl/private/univhub.key'
-----
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:NP
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:Bagmati
Locality Name (eg, city) []:Kathmandu
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:Univhub Private Limited
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:IT Department 
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:univhub.com    
Email Address []:root@univhub.com

Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:
An optional company name []:
```

And my working apache configuration has following lines

```
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

#SSLCertificateFile     /etc/ssl/certs/univhub.csr
#SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private/univhub.key
```

When revert the comented lines, what I get a single line in apache errorlog

```
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Comment: `univhub.csr` is the key signing request, not the Certificate File. And, when you do get a Certificate File, don't forget that you also need to load any intermediate certificate as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSR needs to be validated and turned into a certificate, which is usually what you pay an SSL company for. You would usually buy a certificate and upload your CSR, which would then be returned as a validated certificate.

Comment: There was a download option in the godaddy ssl management option. It is working.

Comment: goDaddy sent me 2 files. One has 1 certificate and another has 3 in it. Using 1'st file woked fine. What is second with 3 certificates for?

Comment: It is GoDaddy's intermediate certificates. They should be available to most browsers or downloadable now but it's good practise to serve them with the `SSLCertificateCAFile` or `SSLCertificateChainFile` setting.